# KeyError: 'No such route named <function login at 0x034993D8>'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

`__init__.py` defined:

```
config.add_route('to_login', '/manage')        
config.add_route('login', '/manage/login')
```

visit `http://xxx.xxx.0.1:6543/manage/` success to get to the login.pt

but in the html form:

```html
<div class="login-form">
<form class="login" action="/manage/login" method="post">
<h1 i18n:translate="">登录</h1>
```

after submit I get an error:

```
2012-10-11 11:22:39,365 ERROR [waitress][Dummy-1] Exception when serving /manage
/login
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Py3Env\lib\site-packages\pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.2-py3.2.egg\pyramid
_debugtoolbar\toolbar.py", line 122, in toolbar_tween
    response = _handler(request)
  File "D:\Py3Env\lib\site-packages\pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.2-py3.2.egg\pyramid
_debugtoolbar\panels\performance.py", line 69, in noresource_timer_handler
    result = handler(request)
```

..........
..........
        response = view(request)
      File "d:\py3env\scripts\dyncms\dyncms\view\login.py", line 51, in login
        login_url = request.route_url(login)
      File "D:\Py3Env\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.3.3-py3.2.egg\pyramid\url.py", lin
    e 208, in route_url
        raise KeyError('No such route named %s' % route_name)
    KeyError: 'No such route named '

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Py3Env\lib\site-packages\waitress-0.8.1-py3.2.egg\waitress\channel.py
", line 329, in service
    task.service()
```

.........
.........
      File "D:\Py3Env\lib\site-packages\pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.2-py3.2.egg\pyramid
    _debugtoolbar\tbtools.py", line 386, in sourcelines
        source = f.read()
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 2080-2081: illega
    l multibyte sequence

anybody knows why?

Comment: Can you paste more of the traceback than just the KeyError? I have no idea at what point in the request handling this may have occurred right now.

Comment: Looks like you have an encoding problem. What is the HTML form encoded as? I'd just stick to UTF-8 for everything.

Comment: in case of encoding error, add `# coding: utf-8` on the first line for utf-8 and replace utf-8 by whatever encoding you're using

Comment: I'm using Python3, dose it need coding: utf-8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to change

```
request.route_url(login)
```

to

```
request.route_url('login')
```